# iOS get user's hometown with swift and latest FBSDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I couldn't find a swift doc for Facebook SDK. I'm using the latest version and I managed to retrieve name, age, mail and profile picture of the user. I can't find out how to find the hometown though.

When I try this :

```
conn.addRequest(req, completionHandler:  { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error != nil){
                println(error)
            } else {
                let loc = result.objectForKey("hometown") // loc is nil

            }
        })
        conn.start()
```

I found nil. I know that ".objectForKey("hometown")" should return a "Page" and not a "String" but I don't know how to handle a page.

Thanks for your help! 
Cheers

EDIT : (thanks to Tobi)
I needed to add the `user_location` in login permissions and then, to find the location, I used :

```
let obj = result.objectForKey("location")
let location = obj.objectForKey("name") as! String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the User Access Token you're using contains the `user_hometown` permission:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_hometown

Also, make sure that you *really* want the `hometown` and not the `location` (current city) of the user. The latter would be the `user_location` permission:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_location

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it by adding the permissions and I used "let obj = result.objectForKey("location")" and then "let location = obj.objectForKey("location")"