# Facebook iOS SDK and Swift: how to get user's hometown?

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

I am working with iOS 9.2 & Swift 2.1 & FBSDKVersion: 4.7.0.

I tried with Graph API Explorer, at that time I am getting the desired output.

The converted code is in Objective-C and I changed it to Swift.

```
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "hometown"], HTTPMethod: "GET")

            graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if ((error) != nil){
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                else{
                    print("fetched details: \(result)")
            })
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error, or just not the results you expected?

Comment: As I understand, everything works, you have no problems, no questions... You just wanted to share what you did?

Comment: It's not working i want to get the hometown of the user who logged via facebook. Now i am getting id only.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124662/ios-get-users-hometown-with-swift-and-latest-fbsdk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031677/facebook-graph-api-get-request-should-contain-fields-parameter-swift-faceb#32031890

Comment: @jose920405 i find out the problem, i don't added user_location permission. I submitted user_hometown item for review. Now it's in review state. Do u know how long it will take.

Comment: @Sudhi9135 It can be up to 5 days if I remember correctly. Although in most cases it is less.

Answer (score 0):

See below example and add **hometown** option into **"fields"** parameter of **FBSDKGraphRequest** object and also change:

```
func fetchUserProfile()
    {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, email, name, picture.width(480).height(480)"])

        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                print("Error took place: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Print entire fetched result: \(result)")

                let id : NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as! String
                print("User ID is: \(id)")

                if let userName = result.valueForKey("name") as? String
                {
                    self.userFullName.text = userName
                }

                if let profilePictureObj = result.valueForKey("picture") as? NSDictionary
                {
                    let data = profilePictureObj.valueForKey("data") as! NSDictionary
                    let pictureUrlString  = data.valueForKey("url") as! String
                    let pictureUrl = NSURL(string: pictureUrlString)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

                        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: pictureUrl!)

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            if let imageData = imageData
                            {
                                let userProfileImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                self.userProfileImage.image = userProfileImage
                                self.userProfileImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Also refer to this link 
[Fetching user details from Facebook in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746486/fetching-user-details-from-facebook-in-ios)

Comment: I know my answer is too late but it will be useful to them who will meet to this question in future.